# ksqlDB topic from Stream returns result only first couple of times

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have created KSQLDB Stream from another KSQLDB stream using CREATE STREAM AS SELECT...
Underlying topic is also created.
When I invoke PRINT  from BEGINNING; for the first time results are displayed correctly in KSQLDB terminal. 
However every subsequent PRINT command returns nothing...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any errors in the ksqlDB server log? And do you run `PRINT .. FROM BEGINNING` each time? or just `PRINT ..` on subsequent attempts?

Comment: Yes I run PRINT FROM BEGINNING each time. I don`t see any errors in ksqldb logs. However I see that topic offset is shifted to the last record...

Comment: What version of ksqlDB are you running? Can you update your question with a transcript of your terminal illustrating exactly what happens?

Comment: KsqlDB 0.9.0. I think that is the latest image. However I just realized that official confluent ksqlDB Image 5.5.0 is not the latest KsqlDB version. Or am I wrong?

Comment: ksqlDB 0.9 is the latest and there is an official Confluent image here (https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/ksqldb-server). There is also an image of ksqlDB as shipped in Confluent Platform (https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-ksql-server) 5.5 which corresponds to ksqlDB 0.7.1

Comment: What is the topic retention time set to on the underlying Kafka topic? Could it be that the messages are being deleted aggressively by the Kafka broker?

Comment: AndrewCoates You are right. That fixed the problem. Thx!